# PHP5.4 "parse_str" behaving unexpectedly

Tags: php, php-5.4

I am using Zend Framework 2's `AbstractRestfulController` to implement a CRUD API in our project. Using the PUT HTTP method invokes the logic for updating an existing entity.

When receiving a PUT request, the `AbstractRestfulController` transforms the request body to an array using PHP's `parse_str` function, but this function does not do what it is supposed to do.

Because it gave me odd results, I tried `parse_str` with the sample data provided in the PHP docs:

```
// sample data from the PHP docs
$content = "first=value&arr[]=foo+bar&arr[]=baz";

// put the parsed variables into $parsedParams
parse_str($content, $parsedParams);
```

`var_dump`ing `$parsedParams` gives me the following

```
array(5) { 
    ["first"]=> string(1) "v" 
    ["lue"]=> string(0) "" 
    ["rr"]=> array(2) { 
        [0]=> string(5) "foo b" 
        [1]=> string(1) "b" 
    } 
    ["r"]=> string(0) "" 
    ["z"]=> string(0) "" 
}
```

Apparently the character "a" confuses `parse_str`, but I have absolutely no idea what's causing this odd behavior. The encoding of the PHP file is UTF-8, server is running Ubuntu 14.04 with PHP 5.4 as a Apache 2.4 module inside a Vagrant environment.

What may be the cause of this? I read about issues with the HTML entity `&amp;` instead of plain `&`'s, but that doesn't seem to apply here.

**UPDATE**

I just ran the same code on the command line in interactive mode via `SSH`ing into the Vagrant machine. In interactive mode `parse_str` works without problem! I then ran my test script from the command line via `$ php /var/www/test.php` which also worked properly. 
Is this a problem with the Apache PHP module or configuration?

Comment: Just tried it with PHP v5.4 and it works without any problems. Perhaps your string contains invisible characters that makes PHP choke? Could you try `echo strlen($content)` and see what you get?

Comment: copied the one you have posted. http://codepad.viper-7.com/FYbCCx seems fine

Comment: strlen($content) gives me a length of 35 which is correct, may it be a problem of my PHP version or something like that?

Comment: I now tried the same code as above in interactive mode on the command line, I have added my findings to the initial question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice how your strings are split on both `&` and `a`?

I think the configuration setting [`arg_separator.input`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.sect.data-handling) is incorrectly set to `"&amp;"` instead of the default `"&"`.

This setting can be set in `php.ini`, `.htaccess`, `httpd.conf` or `.user.ini`. See: [Where a configuration setting may be set](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.modes.php).

**Test program:**

```
<?php

  echo "arg_separator.input = '", ini_get ('arg_separator.input'), "'\n";

  $content = "first=value&arr[]=foo+bar&arr[]=baz";
  parse_str($content, $parsedParams);

  var_dump ($parsedParams);
```

**Output (somewhat compacted) with different settings in `php.ini`:**

```
arg_separator.input = '&'
array(2) {
  ["first"] => string(5) "value"
  ["arr"] => array(2) {
    [0] => string(7) "foo bar"
    [1] => string(3) "baz"
  }
}
```

```
arg_separator.input = '&amp;'
array(5) {
  ["first"] => string(1) "v"
  ["lue"] => string(0) ""
  ["rr"] => array(2) {
    [0] => string(5) "foo b"
    [1] => string(1) "b"
  }
  ["r"] => string(0) ""
  ["z"] => string(0) ""
}
```

---

The configuration setting [`arg_separator.output`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.sect.data-handling) also defaults to `"&"`. Setting this to `"&amp;"` *might* be okay if you *only* produce HTML output. But you will run into trouble if you want to use [`http_build_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) to produce an HTTP `Location:` header, or in other situations where an HTML entity reference is not suitable.

**Test program:**

```
<?php

  echo "arg_separator.output = '", ini_get ('arg_separator.output'), "'\n";

  $q = http_build_query (array ('a' => 0, 'b' => 1, 'c' => 2));
  echo $q, "\n";
```

**Output with different settings in `php.ini`:**

```
arg_separator.output = '&'
a=0&b=1&c=2
```

```
arg_separator.output = '&amp;'
a=0&amp;b=1&amp;c=2
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was causing the issue! Would have taken me years to figure that out by myself. When setting up the Vagrant environment I copied the php.ini from our production server (a shared environment) to the Vagrant machine, guess I have to look out for this problem on the production server too. Can I safely leave arg_seperator.output as "&amp;" though?